# Is there any Progress 4GL statement used for editing an ASCII files?

Tags: progress-4gl

Is there any 4GL statement used for editing an ASCII files from the disk, if so how?

Answer (score 8):

Editing involves reading a file, probably using IMPORT, then manipulating the text using string functions like REPLACE() and finally writing the result probably using PUT.  Something like this:

```
define stream inFile.
define stream outFile.

define variable txtLine as character no-undo.

input stream inFile from "input.txt".
output stream outFile to "output.txt".

repeat:

  import stream inFile unformatted txtLine.

  txtLine = replace( txtLine, "abc", "123" ).   /* edit something */

  put stream outFile unformatted txtLine skip.

end.

input stream inFile close.
output stream outFile close.
```

Comment: That's a fairly "old-school" approach suitable for legacy code.  In the oe10+ world you can avoid the INPUT & OUTPUT streams as well as IMPORT and PUT by using COPY-LOB instead (as Carl's answer shows).

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You can use a STREAM to do so.

```
/* Define a new named stream */
DEF STREAM myStream.

/* Define the output location of the stream */
OUTPUT STREAM myStream TO VALUE("c:\text.txt").

/* Write some text into the file */
PUT STREAM myStream UNFORMATTED "Does this work?".

/* Close the stream now that we're done with it */
OUTPUT STREAM myStream CLOSE.
```

Comment: STREAM is just a keyword for naming a file descriptor.  It doesn't "edit" anything per se.

Answer (score 0):

Progress could call operating system editor:

OS-COMMAND("vi /tmp/yoyo.txt").

Answer (score 0):

You could use copy-lob to read and write the file

```
DEF VAR lContents AS LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

/* read file */
COPY-LOB FROM FILE "ascii.txt" TO lContents.
/* change Contents, e.g. all capital letters */
lContents = CAPS(lContents).
/* save file */
COPY-LOB lContents TO FILE "ascii.txt".
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think that for "editing" you mean to be able to read and then show the file in screen and manipulate the file?

If so then here you have an easy one, of course, the size of the file can't be bigger than the max. capacity of a vchar variable:

```
def var fileline as char format "x(250)".  /* or shorter or longer, up to you*/
def var filedit as char.

/*you have to quote it to obtain & line into teh charvar*/

unix silent quoter kk.txt > kk.quoted.

input from kk.quoted no-echo.


repeat:

   set fileline.

   filedit = filedit + (fileline + chr(13) + chr(10)) .

end.

input close.

update filedit view-as editor size 65 by 10.
```

Sure you can manage to save the file once edited ;-)